# How to wait for second dropdown to load based on the first using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, wait

Using selenium I'm trying to test the forms on [this page](https://ywamconverge.org/students/setup/about_you?locale=en). Via code below, I'm able to select an item from the first dropdown menu but it crashes before being able to select from the second dropdown.

```
def test_apply_forms(self):
        FILE_PATH = "tests/forms/apply.csv"
        with open(FILE_PATH) as csv_file:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=",")
            headers = next(csv_reader)
            for row in csv_reader:
                form = dict(zip(headers, row))

                # Your Internship
                dropdown_xpath = "//span[@id='select2-chosen-2']"
                self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(dropdown_xpath).click()
                choice_xpath = f"//div[contains(text(),'{form[headers[0]]}')]"
                self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(choice_xpath).click()

                # Your Session
                dropdown_xpath = "//span[contains(text(),'Choose a session')]"
                self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(dropdown_xpath).click()
                choice_xpath = f"//div[contains(text(),'{form[headers[1]]}')]"
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(choice_xpath).click()
```

It is not able to find the dropdown elements for the second dropdown. Can anybody help troubleshoot? (the last line in the code is indented correctly in my code)

Answer (score -1):

you can try to add wait(fluent preferably) between two drop-downs.